# How to efficiently get a rolling 7-day count of distinct customers for each transaction_date in a Large MySQL Table?

Tags: python, sql, mysql

I have a MySQL table, `my_table`, approximately 38 GB in size, with the following structure:

```
DESC my_table;
+------------------+----------+-----+-----+
| Field            | Type     | Null| Key |
+------------------+----------+-----+-----+
| date_available   | date     | NO  | PRI |
| transaction_date | datetime | NO  | PRI |
| customer_id      | char(36) | NO  | PRI |
| transaction_count| bigint   | YES |     |
+------------------+----------+-----+-----+
```

For each transaction_date, I want to get the count of distinct customers for the last 7 days. For example, for `2020-03-07`, I want to count all unique customers between `2020-03-01` and `2020-03-07`, inclusive.

My initial attempt was using a subquery with group_concat:

```
SELECT group_concat(distinct customer_id) AS cust_id, transaction_date 
FROM my_table 
WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN "2019-12-26" AND "2023-09-05" 
GROUP BY transaction_date;
```

However, this query, which takes approximately 14 minutes to execute, only gives me the unique customers for each day.
In an attempt to process this data further in Python, I loaded the results into a DataFrame:

```
with ENGINE.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute("SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 999999999999999999")
    %time res = pd.read_sql(text(query), conn)
```

To expand the grouped customer IDs and get the count for the rolling window, I tried to use the explode method:

```
res['cust_id'] = res.explode('cust_id')[['cust_id', 'transaction_date']]
```

However, this line of code causes my Python kernel to die, probably because of memory exhaustion due to the large number of unique customers on each date.

I also struggled to do this computation in the query itself rather than trying to do this in Python. I tried to expand the above query to account for the last 7 days for each transaction date using the following query:

```
SELECT group_concat(cust_id) AS concatenated_cust_ids,transaction_date 
FROM 
(
    SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT customer_id) AS cust_id, transaction_date 
    FROM my_table
    WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN '2019-12-26' AND '2023-09-05' 
    GROUP BY transaction_date
) AS intermediate
WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(transaction_date, INTERVAL 6 DAY) AND transaction_date 
GROUP BY transaction_date;
```

For each `transaction_date`, the idea is to apply group_concat on the results achieved from inner group_concat for 7 days(previous 6 + the `transaction_date` itself)
However, I realized that the logic in this query is flawed because using DATE_SUB(transaction_date, INTERVAL 6 DAY) and transaction_date in the same WHERE clause leads to a self-referential condition. Essentially, for each date in the subquery, the outer query's condition always evaluates to true.

I also attempted a join-based solution as follows:

```
SELECT t1.transaction_date, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.customer_id) as unique_customers
FROM 
my_table t1 JOIN my_table t2 
ON t2.transaction_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(t1.transaction_date, INTERVAL 6 DAY) 
AND t1.transaction_date
WHERE t1.transaction_date BETWEEN "2019-12-26" AND "2023-09-05"
GROUP BY t1.transaction_date
ORDER BY t1.transaction_date;
```

However, given that my table is approximately 38GB in size, I'm concerned about the performance implications of using a JOIN.

Could someone guide me on:

- An optimized approach to achieve this directly in SQL without facing performance issues.
- If doing this in SQL isn't feasible, how can I handle the large data frame in Python to get my desired output without exhausting memory?

EDIT: Adding index information on the table
The indexes on the table are as follows

```
mysql> show indexes from my_table;
+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name    | Seq_in_index | Column_name      | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| my_table |          0 | PRIMARY     |            1 | date_available   | A         |      333594 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| my_table |          0 | PRIMARY     |            2 | transaction_date | A         |     2181937 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| my_table |          0 | PRIMARY     |            3 | customer_id      | A         |   288982624 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| my_table |          1 | au_date_idx |            1 | transaction_date | A         |     1785462 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| my_table |          1 | au_date_idx |            2 | date_available   | A         |     1785462 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: When talking about database performance, there is always one important question: Did you create indexes for the fields that you use in the query?

Comment: Yes, I did create indexes. I've edited my question to show the table index information.

Comment: Since the query is to perform an aggregation job of customer_id based on transaction_date, I would create an index for (transaction_date,customer_id) first. Then try your join_based query again. Please also provide result of  `explain` and `explain analyze` on your query.

Comment: And since the base table is huge, performance-wise I would really recommend creating a result table storing calculated data up until yesterday. And deploy an event schedule to calculate daily result up until yesterday. The reason why I am against using a trigger to keep the  result table up-to-date is if the insert rate is high on the base table, the impact will be huge .